# How to solve $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$ with trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

**The integral**

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$$

I've found the variable

$$x=2\sin\theta$$

$$x^2=4\sin^2\theta$$

$$dx=2\cos\theta\,d\theta$$

Which gave me by substitution

$$\int\frac{2\cos\theta}{4-\sqrt{4\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta$$
$$\int\frac{\cos\theta}{2-\sin\theta}\,d\theta$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \cos\theta \,d\theta-\int\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\,d\theta$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \cos\theta \,d\theta-\int\cot\theta \,d\theta$$
$$= \frac{\sin\theta}{2}-\ln|\sin\theta| + C$$

Now if I look at the expected answer, it should be

$$\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+C$$

What am I missing ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry, it was a typo, edited.

Comment: It’s better, but that first step is still off: where are you getting the first $4$ in the denominator? You should have $$\sqrt{4-4\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{4\cos^2\theta}=2\cos\theta\;.$$

Comment: Oops, actually I think the denominator should be $\sqrt{4-4\sin^2\theta}$ right ? Just saw your edit, great this was probably my mistake.. Let me see if I can fix it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how does $4-4sin^2\theta$ becomes $4cos^2\theta$ ?

Comment: $4-4\sin^2\theta=4(1-\sin^2\theta)=4\cos^2\theta$, from the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$. That’s actually *why* you use the trig substitution.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Great, then I was able to resolve to $\theta$, but how does that becomes $\arcsin(\frac{x}{2})$ ?

Comment: Recall that $x=2\sin\theta$, and solve for $\theta$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: I see, well thanks a lot I understand now !

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: Isn't $x=2t$, so the integral becomes $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\arcsin t+c$, easier? What's the purpose of a complicated trigonometric substitution?

Comment: @egreg We already know there is easier solution, however as we are starting to learn trigonometric substitution, they ask us to prove simple case.

Answer (score 2):

Substitution of $x=2\sin\theta$ implies that $\sqrt{4-x^2}=\sqrt{4-4\sin^2\theta}=2\cos\theta$.  Then,

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\int \frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{\cos\theta}=\theta+C$$
where $C$ is a constant of integration.  But, $\theta=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.  So,

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution is correct, but you should have $\sqrt{4-4\sin^2 \theta}$ in the denominator. You cannot break the square root as you have done. Moreover, $\frac{\cos\theta}{2-\sin\theta}$ *is not* the same as $\frac{1}{2}\cos\theta - \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$. Try doing this with numbers; it won't work there, and it doesn't work here either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Brian M. Scott already pointed this in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your big mistake is that you apparently thought that $\sqrt{4-4\sin^2\theta}$ is the same as $4-\sqrt{4\sin^2\theta}$.  Nothing is correct after that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use trigonometric substitution? Because you can solve it easier using regular substitution. First:
$$\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4(1-\frac{x^2}{4})}}}=\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{2})^2}}}$$
We use substitution $\frac{x}{2}=t ; \frac{dx}{2}=dt$.
Now we have:
$$\int{\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}}=arcsint=arcsin\frac{x}{2}+c$$